# How to get all the id's who poked using javascript

Tags: javascript

Using firebug, i get the `html` as following-

```
<a rel="async-post" ajaxify="/ajax/pokes/poke_inline.php?uid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&amp;pokeback=1" href="#" class="uiIconText"><i style="top: 0px;" class="img sp_1lbo22 sx_3b5b96"></i>Poke Back</a>
```

To get the uid, I am using `getElementsByTagName('a')` function then finding `ajaxify` property. Below is my code-

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
   var ajaxify = elements[i].ajaxify;
   if (!ajaxify) {
      continue;
   }
   var uid = ajaxify.match(/uid=([0-9]*)/)[1];
   alert(uid);
}
```

After running  my code in firebug, i am getting `undefined` in console as below.

```
>>> var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a'...ify.match(/uid=([0-9]*)/)[1];     alert(uid);  }

undefined
```

How can i get all the id's who poked using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between an element's *properties* and an element's *attributes*. Most notably an `<input/>`'s `value` *attribute* represents the default value, whereas the `value` *property* is the current value.

Try using `ajaxify = elements[i].getAttribute("ajaxify")` and see if that helps.

Comment: I've tested and it does seem to work if you use `hasAttribute` and/or `getAttribute`. But apart from the fact that attributes hold the default values and properties hold the current, why wouldn't the elements have an `ajaxify` property?

Comment: @ianpgall: my aim is just to get all the id's, who poked on facebook. can you suggest me any other javascript code using DOM?